# Ionic - how to set meta title/description/og:image for dynamic page?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Is there any wayw to set meta title/description/og:image for dynamic page?

for example, adding the following meta tag in the HEADER (same component)

- Product 1

`<meta property="og:image" content="product-1-image.png" />`

- Product 2

`<meta property="og:image" content="product-2-image.png" />`

Comment: Just change the propertive by code?

Comment: Really, I am facing with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular provide Title and Meta which you could use to update both.

```
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

constructor(public meta: Meta, public title: Title, ...) { }

...

this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: description }); 
this.title.setTitle(title);
```

You can also create a service